# Using Jquery to toggle class based on menu item clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menubar

Ok im working on this website where Id like to have the content of a div change to content based on the menu item clicked. I do not have pages for the different menu items but I have all the different content in divs in the index page. I would like to incorporate JQuery but I just cannot seem to find a way to link the menu item class or id to the corresponding div element. My code below":

```
<html>
<body>
    <div class="navbar grid_12">
                <ul>
                    <li class="btn" id="home"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="btn" id="about"><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
                    <li class="btn" id="gallery"><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
                    <li class="btn" id="resume"><a href="#">Resume</a></li>
                    <li class="btn" id="contact"><a href="#">Contact Me</a></li>
                </ul>
     </div>
     <div class="content-container">
      <div class="bio content">
        About me content
      </div>
     <div class="contact content">
        Contact me content
     </div> 
     <div class="gallery content">
        gallery content
     </div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

etc..

as for my JQuery coding so far this is where i am after hours of trying different things out

```
       //Update Content-Container Div 
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $main = $(".content-container");
    var $section = $(".content");

    $("#about").click(function(){
        $main.empty();
        $main.find(".bio");
        $(".bio").show();        
    });

});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of writing individual handlers for each menu item, use a `data-*` attribute to refer to a particular content which need to be displayed, then in the click handler use that attribute to decide which content has to be displayed

```
<div class="navbar grid_12">
    <ul>
        <li class="btn" id="home"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="btn" id="about" data-target=".bio"><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
        <li class="btn" id="gallery" data-target=".gallery"><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
        <li class="btn" id="resume"><a href="#">Resume</a></li>
        <li class="btn" id="contact" data-target=".contact"><a href="#">Contact Me</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="content-container">
    <div class="bio content">
        About me content
    </div>
    <div class="contact content">
        Contact me content
    </div> 
    <div class="gallery content">
        gallery content
    </div>
</div>
```

then

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $main = $(".content-container");
    var $section = $(".content").hide();

    $(".navbar li.btn").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $section.hide();
        var target = $(this).data('target');
        if(target){
            $section.filter(target).show();
        }
    });

});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/tM9Nj/)

Comment: This worked immediately! Thanks guys I suppose I need to work a little more with JQuery because I feel like i knew the logic but finding the code was not as simple.Practice Practice Practice!

Answer (score 3):

Check out [jquery tabs](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/http://jqueryui.com/tabs/),
I think you need this.

```
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>jQuery UI Tabs - Default functionality</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
      <script>
      $(function() {
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
      });
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="tabs">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">About Me</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-4">Resume</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-5">Contact Me</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div id="tabs-1">
        <p>Home content</p>
      </div>
      <div id="tabs-2">
        <p>About me content</p>
      </div>
      <div id="tabs-3">
        <p>Gallery content </p>
      </div>
       <div id="tabs-4">
        <p>Resume content </p>
      </div>
       <div id="tabs-5">
        <p>Contact Me content </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

Assuming `id`s are associated with relevant classes.

HTML:

```
<li class="btn" id="bio"><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
```

JS:

```
$(".btn").click(function () {
    $(".content-container .content").hide();
    $(".content-container").find("."+$(this).attr("id")).show();    
});
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/TmWVF/)

Answer (score 2):

Here I initially hid everything, then based on what links you click, the page displays the correct content.  Note that your about page has the wrong id attribute so it will not work but your contact and gallery pages work.  This is roughly how the twitter bootstrap framework works, I do suggest you look at that.

```
var $main = $(".content-container");
var $section = $(".content");
$section.hide();

$("li.btn").on('click', function() {
    var link_id = $(this).attr('id');
    var content = $main.find("." + link_id);
    $section.hide();
    content.show();
})
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Av4JZ/)

Answer (score 1):

```
const containers = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.content'));
// Slicing for link as it's not related to changing the slide content,
// so we don't want to bind behaviour to it.
const links = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.navbar ul .btn a')).slice(1);

$(function() {
   hideEls(containers);
});

function hideEls (els) {
  if (Array.isArray(els)) {
    els.forEach(el => {
      el.style.display = 'none';
    });
  }
  return;
}

function showEl (els, i, e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  hideEls(els);
  els[i].style.display = 'block';
}

links.forEach((link, i) => {
  link.addEventListener('click', showEl.bind(null, containers, i));
});
```

Here's a [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Dd6dR/7/)

Comment: I was thinking of using your code due to your using index of items, but when I ran your code in the fiddle the first thing that happens is the hidden content flashes, the second thing that happens is the links are not targeting the right content to show... i.e.: _Resume_ link shows _Gallery content_, _Gallery_ shows _contact me content_...

Comment: @Chris22 Wow, blast for the past.  You're right!  I've updated my answer (from 3 years ago) to no longer use jQuery, and to actually work (still uses indexes).  Have also updated the fiddle.  Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for replying and updating your code -- looks awesome!  There's still an issue with the links not targeting the right content.  _Resume_ link shows _gallery_, _Contact me_ show _Resume_ and _Gallery_ shows _Contact me_...

Comment: Derp.  Forgot to update the content in the markup.  Indexing is working correctly, just need to update the fiddle so the container indexes match the link indexes.

Comment: great work!  thank you for continuing to update this solution.  It is working good now, still getting that flash of the hidden content though when refreshing/loading the fiddle...I haven't used ES6 and not sure if the fiddle is 'fighting' with that version of JS?

Comment: If you just set the content to be `display: none` initially (either through css or inline as a style attribute) then that shouldn't happen.